# Trading Post version of Splendor

Tags: splendor

When playing the Trading Post version of Splendor, are you required to have the 3 black bonuses power to get the 5 prestige points for having the 5 green bonuses and 1 noble tile power?

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/splendor/cites-of-splendor.php) on ultraboardgames.com they explain the rules for the different powers and how to get them.

[image]

**Requirement**: You must have 3 black bonuses.

**Power**: 1 prestige point for each of your coats of arms on the board.

[image]

**Requirement**: You must have 5 green bonuses and 1 noble tile.

**Power**: 5 prestige points.

For the 5 prestige points the only thing you need is the 5 green bonuses and 1 noble tile. For the prestige point for your coats of arms you only need to have the 3 black bonuses.
The bonuses are independent from each other so you can get any of them at the time you have the requirements.